# How to block HTML regions from edition CKEDITOR/WYSIWYG

Tags: c#, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have tried:

```
<p contenteditable ="false">Write protected text</p>
```

But it does not work, text still editable regardless of the contenteditable attribute set to "false", any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

the contenteditable ="false" attribute does lock the content of the HTML region inside the CKEDITOR.